# logrotate, syslog-ng and loosing log

Tags: netcat, piping, logrotate, syslog-ng

**Background**

1. Apache server running on a machine and producing logs into `/var/log/httpd/error_log`
2. Using `syslog-ng` to send log to a port `5140`
3. Eventually it will be consumed by `kafka producer` to be send to a topic
4. `logrotate` rotates `/var/log/httpd/error_log` every hour

**Settings**

*syslog-ng.conf*

```
options {                                                                                                                             
    flush_lines (0);                                                                                                                
    time_reopen (10);                                                                                                               
    log_fifo_size (1000);                                                                                                          
    long_hostnames (off);                                                                                                           
    use_dns (no);                                                                                                                   
    use_fqdn (no);                                                                                                                  
    create_dirs (no);                                                                                                               
    keep_hostname (no);                                                                                                             
};

source s_apache2 {
    file("/var/log/httpd/error_log" flags(no-parse));
}


destination loghost {
    tcp("*.*.*.*" port(5140) template("$MSG\n")); 
}
```

*logrotate.hourly.conf*

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log {
  copytruncate
  rotate 4
  dateext
  missingok
  ifempty
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**Log Consumption**

```
 nc -k -l 5140 | grep "STATS:" | java program
```

This java program is essentially a `kafka-producer` and sends data to kafka cluster

**Problem**

Between the `logrotate` initiating `copytruncate` and `syslog-ng` reading data from `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, some data is sent to this file but is not captured by `syslog-ng` and hence is not pushed to `kafka-cluster`

Is there any sane way to read logs continuously without losing from a file which is rotated by `logrotate` periodically ?

Answer (score 0):

Does logrotate reload syslog-ng on rotating the log? Without it syslog-ng learns about the truncation of the file slower.